# Why exception specifications cannot be useful?

Tags: c++, templates, exception, exception-specification

I have read lots of arguments about (not) using `throw(X)` in function signatures, and I think the way it's specified in ISO C++ (and implemented in current compilers) it's rather useless. But why compiler cannot simply **enforce** exception-correctness at compile time?

If I write function/method definition that contains `throw(A,B,C)` in it's signature, the compiler should not have many problems in figuring out if implementation of given function is exception-correct. That means that function body has

- no `throw`'s other than `throw A; throw B; throw C;`;
- no function/method call that have throw-signatures less restrictive than `throw (A,B,C)`;

, at least outside `try{}catch()` catching other thrown types. If compiler raises error if these requirements are not met, then all functions should be "safe" and no runtime functions like `unexpected()` would be required. All this would be assured at compile-time.

```
void fooA() throw (A){
}

void fooAB() throw (A,B){
}

void fooABC() throw (A,B,C){
}


void bar() throw (A){

    throw A();   // ok
    throw B();   // Compiler error

    fooA();      // ok
    fooAB();     // compiler error
    fooABC();    // compiler error

    try{
       throw A();   // ok
       throw B();   // ok
       throw C();   // Compiler error

       fooA();   // ok
       fooAB();  // ok
       fooABC(); // compiler error
    } catch (B){}
}
```

This would require that all non-C++ realm code was either `throw()` specified by default (`extern "C"` should assume it by default), or if there is some exception interoperability then appropriate headers (for C++ at least) should be `throw`-specified as well. Failure to do so could be compared to using headers with different function/method return type in different compilation units. While it's not producing warnings or errors, it's obviously wrong - and as thrown exceptions are part of signature, they should also match.

If we enforce such constrains it would have three effects:

- It would remove all those implicit `try{}catch` blocks, otherwise required for runtime checking, thus improving exception-handling performance.
- The argument that "Exceptions are making our library too big, so we switch them off"; would disappear, as most of additional code lies in those unnecessary implicit throw/catch instructions at every function call. If code was properly `throw`-specified, most of it wouldn't be added by compiler.
- It would make most of the programing world furious, as nobody ever seemed to like
  exceptions. Now, as these are actually usable, we need to learn how to use them.

If we used some compatibility compiler flags for older code it wouldn't break anything, but as new exception-code would be quicker, there would be a good motivation not to write new code using it.

To summarize my question: Why such enforcement is not required by ISO C++? Are there any strong reasons for it not to be? I always thought that exceptions are just another function's return value, but one that is governed automatically, so you can avoid writing functions like

```
std::pair<int, bool> str2int(std::string s);
int str2int(std::string s, bool* ok);
```

plus additional auto-destruction of variables and propagation through multiple functions up the stack so you don't need code like

```
int doThis(){

    int err=0;

    [...]

    if ((err = doThat())){
        return err;
    }

    [...]

}
```

;and if you can require function to `return` only the correct type, why can't you require it to `throw` it?

Why can't exception specifiers be better? Why weren't they made like I described from the start?

PS I know there might be some issues with exceptions and templates - depending on answers to this question perhaps i will ask another one about it - for now let us just forget templates.

**EDIT** (in response to @NicolBolas):

> What kind of optimization could the compiler do with exception class X that it couldn't do with Y?

Compare:

```
void fooA() throw (A){
}

void fooAB() throw (A,B){
}

void fooABC() throw (A,B,C){
}


void bar() throw (){

    try{
       fooA();
         // if (exception == A) goto A_catch
       fooAB();
         // if (exception == A) goto A_catch
         // if (exception == B) goto B_catch
       fooABC();
         // if (exception == A) goto A_catch
         // if (exception == B) goto B_catch
         // if (exception == C) goto C_catch
    }
    catch (A){  // :A_catch
      [...]
    }
    catch (B){  // :B_catch
      [...]
    }
    catch (C){  // :C_catch
      [...]
    }
}
```

and:

```
void fooA(){
}

void fooAB(){
}

void fooABC(){
}


void bar(){

    try{
       fooA();
         // if (exception == A) goto A_catch;
         // if (exception == B) goto B_catch;
         // if (exception == C) goto C_catch;
         // if (exception == other) return exception;
       fooAB();
         // if (exception == A) goto A_catch;
         // if (exception == B) goto B_catch;
         // if (exception == C) goto C_catch;
         // if (exception == other) return exception;
       fooABC();
         // if (exception == A) goto A_catch;
         // if (exception == B) goto B_catch;
         // if (exception == C) goto C_catch;
         // if (exception == other) return exception;
    }
    catch (A){  // :A_catch
      [...]
    }
    catch (B){  // :B_catch
      [...]
    }
    catch (C){  // :C_catch
      [...]
    }
}
```

Here I included some pseudo-code that compiler would have generated no assembly level. As you can see, knowing what exceptions you can get can reduce amount of code. If we had some additional variables to destroy here, additional code would have been even longer.

Comment: We're very happy that C++ is not Java and didn't introduce checked exceptions.

Comment: As stated in the other comment, I think that checked exceptions has never been introduced because nobody cares (and many people think that there's more than enough hassle just with `const`).

Comment: In other words to avoid "It would make most of the programing world furious, as nobody ever seemed to like exceptions. Now, as these are actually usable, we need to learn how to use them." :)

Comment: @CatPlusPlus why happy? While it makes programmer life a slight bit easier, it is also making exceptions slower, and in many cases code writers resign from exceptions at all and switch it off while compiling. This way this rather nice feature is completely unused because of laziness of programmers. `Programmers don't want to hear about it` - should that really be a criteria for language design?

Comment: Only silly game developers turn core language features off because PERFORMANCE. Checked exceptions are annoying without extensive language support (and no, Java-level is not enough), and C++ is complex enough as it is.

Comment: And yes, not annoying the hell out of programmers should be a criterion for language design.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus write your functions without any specifiers (as most programmers already do) if it's annoying to you, and no exception-management will ever show up to you. But let others work with it if they want. Or is is simply like: "Ewww... nobody will use it anyway so we will not waste our time to standarize/implement this". BTW: what do you mean by "extensive language support". What do you think C++ is missing?

Comment: @j_rubik then all the advantages you state will go down the drain because when face with a call to `void f()` the compiler is hopeless again.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes If i understand you right, then yes, you are right. When calling C++ function `void f()` the compiler has no chance to optimize, because such signature says this function can throw anything. If it does, then there is no space for optimization anyway. And if it doesn't, then the guilty one is creator of this function - then you have to give the compiler a hint, perhaps `template <typename Ret, typename ...Args, Ret (*Func)(Args...)> inline Ret perhaps_exception(Func f, Args... args, bool* excp=0) { try{ return f(args); }catch(...){ if (excp) *excp=true; } return Ret();  }`

Comment: @j_kubik what do you think people in Java do? `throws Exception` is often part of a function's signature, because this feature is so annoyingly unproductive. Or sometimes they just `try { ... } catch(Exception) { log_and_forget(); }` which is even worse. *This is actually what some IDEs generate by default as a fix for the compiler errors*. It's that bad. Programmers do those kinds of things when faced with checked exceptions, because, at least when specified as in Java (which is quite similar to your description here) they hurt productivity, and *these "fixes" only make the problem worse*.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes if not having a specifier implied 'throws anything' then checked exceptions could be completely ignored anwhere they're not useful. No need for `throws Exception` or `catch(...) {log_and_forget();}`. But for those that do want the compiler checked guarantees they'd be available with no inconvenience to anyone else..

Comment: @bames53 Those that do want the guarantees can't properly call a function that was written by those that don't care.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Seems to me that we are standing here in the for between "good code" and "quick-to-write code" then, are we?

Comment: Only if you assume that all code that doesn't manually propagate all exceptions from the throw site to the catch site is not good code. If you do, I can't possibly make my view seem convincing to you.

Comment: As my edit shows it is (slightly, I admit) suboptimal. I simply think that this slight difference is not worth much for programmers these days.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes True, for the most part, but I don't see that as an argument against it.

Comment: Why do you assume compilers currently implement exceptions that way? Anyway, to just make it clear, what I don't like about this is only the fact that you have to *manually* propagate the exceptions by keeping the signatures in sync. I like exceptions because I can transmit an error condition from the point where it happens to the point where it is handled *without the intervening functions in the middle having to care about it*. Having to maintain throws signatures like this means I lose that and I'm back to manual propagation of errors (even if compiler-enforced, it's still manual).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I think even checked exceptions are primarily useful when specifying that no exceptions are thrown. In which case you're not manually propagating anything, you're just asking the compiler to guarantee that nothing you call throws exceptions, and signaling to callers that they have the same guarantee from you.

Comment: One of the reasons is: that you know that code will not throw anything else than you expect it to.If it can throw anything then you always need a parachute `catch(...)`which cannot really do anything with exception apart from logging "unknown exception".If you have your try/catch instruction, you just look at called functions declarations, and you instantly know what exceptions you need to catch.This limitation is not to piss you off, it's to make you avoid mistakes, especially the ones that show "unknown error" to the user in the situation when he could resolve the problem if knew what it was

Comment: `catch (const std::exception&)`, not `catch (...)`. If you throw things that aren't `std::exception`, you deserve the pain. There's never "unknown exception" condition in properly written code (see Boost.Exception's `diagnostic_information`), and exception specifiers are not needed for that.

Comment: Also, for marking "never throws" functions you have `noexcept`.

Comment: Also, `throw()` say never throws too, and it's the only practically useful exception spec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compiler-verified exceptions as part of a function's signature have two (theoretical) advantages: compiler optimizations and compile-time error checking.

What is the difference, in terms of the compiler, between a function that throws exception class `X` and class `Y`? Ultimately... nothing at all. What kind of optimization could the compiler do with exception class `X` that it couldn't do with `Y`? Unless `std::exception` were special (and `X` were derived from it, while `Y` was not), what would it matter to the compiler?

Ultimately, the only thing a compiler would care about in terms of optimization is whether a function will throw *any* exceptions or not. That's why the standards committee for C++11 ditched `throw(...)` in favor of `noexcept`, which states that the function will throw nothing.

As for compile-time error checking, Java clearly shows how well this works. You're writing a function, `foo`. Your design has that it throws `X` and `Y`. Other pieces of code use `foo`, and they throw whatever `foo` throws. But the exception specification doesn't say "whatever `foo` throws". It must list `X` and `Y` specifically.

Now you go back and change `foo` so that it no longer throws `X`, but now it throws `Z`. Suddenly, the entire project stops compiling. You must now go to every function that throws whatever `foo` threw just to change its exception specification to match `foo`.

Eventually, a programmer just throws up their hand and says that it throws any exception. When you abandon a feature like that, it's a de facto admission that the feature is doing more harm than good.

It's not that they *cannot* be useful. It's just that actual use of them shows that they're generally not useful. So there's no point.

Plus, remember that C++'s specification states that no specification means that anything will be thrown, not nothing (as in Java). The simplest way to use the language is exactly that way: no checking. So there are going to be plenty of people who don't want the bother of using it.

What good is a feature that many don't want to bother with, and even those who do will generally get a lot of grief out of it?

Comment: "Now you go back and change foo so that it no longer throws X, but now it throws Z. Suddenly, the entire project stops compiling." And what if you change parameters, or reorder them? Or change result type? It's as much of change in function's signature as changing throw-specification.

Comment: @j_kubik It's not as pervasive, because changing a function's parameters only affects direct callers.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes That might be true but consider that scenario: `void DisplayAlert(std::string text);` displays alerts from some stack-deep function. Now some users of this app want it in some specific screen part, so programmer changes it to `void DisplayAlert(std::string text, int x, int y);`. The change affects only direct caller, but info about user preferences was left many levels up-the stack. Now you have to modify all those methods to pass this info as well. You are changing data propagating through the call-stack in both cases: exception-specification change and above change.

Comment: If functions upper the stack don't want to know or care about new exception, then just `try{}catch` at direct caller.

Comment: What if I could simply change two things when I change a throws-spec: the thrower and the catcher? Why should every single function in the middle need changing if it's not involved in the process at all? Why do I have to edit half my codebase because two lines of code need fixing?

Comment: I have my `int x, int y` parameters in my main, I need to get them down the stack, why should I change all the functions on the way? These functions themselves don't need those values, right? Those two lines of code change a bit meaning of the code. The throw-specs are defining how function could end, and thus completing it's definition.

Comment: "_ditched `throw(...)`_" The `...` is a token. Do you mean literally `throw(...)` or `throw(FOO)` so some syntax production FOO?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes "_Why do I have to edit half my codebase because two lines of code need fixing?_" Because half your functions can now throw these at their caller; unless you have "callbacks"/function ptr/functors passed deep in the code (which creates loads of other issues than exceptions); intermediates are responsible also. **Do you want to deal of all the sub-sub-sub-contractors of the person you paid to redo your house?**

Answer (score 1):

> That means that function body has
>
> no throw's other than throw A; throw B; throw C;;
> no function/method call that have throw-signatures less restrictive than throw (A,B,C);

Don't forget that code can be compiled on different machines at different times and only linked together at runtime, via dynamic libraries. The compiler may have a *local* version of the signature of a called function but it may not match with the version actually used at runtime. (I presume the linker could be modified to forbid linking if exceptions don't match perfectly, but that could introduce more annoyances than it solves.)

Comment: Well, mismatching function signatures is a source of danger already, so this problem could be ignored. I think the real reason here is that nobody cares about enforced exception specifications.

Comment: @MatteoItalia my opinion as well ;)

Comment: @MatteoItalia Exception spec have always been enforced in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Throw specifications could be useful in some cases, especially on embedded systems, where the alternative would be to forbid exceptions altogether.  Among other things, if the only functions that are allowed to throw are those which are explicitly specified as such, then it is possible to eliminate exception-handling overhead when calling functions which cannot throw.  Note that even in systems which use "metadata" for exception handling, the fact that an exception handler must be able to make sense of stack frames precludes optimizations which might otherwise be possible.

Another situation where throw specifications could be useful would be if the compiler allowed `catch` statements to specify that they should only catch exceptions which did not bubble up through any layers where they were not "expected".  One major weakness with the exception handling concepts in C++ and languages which borrow from it is that there's no nice way to distinguish an exception which occurs in a called routine, for a condition documented thereby, from an exception which occurs in a nested subroutine, for reasons the directly-called routine did not expect.  It would be helpful if a `catch` statement could act upon the former without catching the latter.

Comment: "One major weakness with the exception handling concepts in C++ and languages which borrow from it is that there's no nice way to distinguish an exception which occurs in a called routine, for a condition documented thereby, from an exception which occurs in a nested subroutine, for reasons the directly-called routine did not expect. It would be helpful if a catch statement could act upon the former without catching the latter." I always thought that this exception-transparency was a good thing.

Comment: "_the fact that an exception handler must be able to make sense of stack frames precludes optimizations which might otherwise be possible._" It evidently does not absolutely prevent any optimization, by definition. The exception handling code is only destructing local objects that would have been destroyed, so there was enough info to do that in the 1st place. That info can be made harder to find though: fine optimizations and simple stack unwind code are not compatible. Arbitrary except handling code is compatible w/ any optimization. It's a trivial property.

Comment: @curiousguy: That is true for leaf functions, but not for the more general case where called functions might throw exceptions the caller doesn't know about.

Comment: @supercat No, it's inherently true of anything; pls give a specific counter.

Comment: @curiousguy: If `foo` which catches a certain exception type `E` makes an indirect function call that happens to call `bar`, which knows nothing about that exception type and may push arbitrary stuff on the stack before calling `boz`, which throws an `E`, the exception-handling code will need to have some way of locating `foo`'s stack frame.  If all functions use a consistent stack frame format that forms a clean linked list, that can be simple.  If all functions are built with tools that produce the same form of metadata for every return address, it could be harder but workable.

Comment: @curiousguy: If, however, any calls pass through an outside function whose stack format is unknown, and for which metadata is unavailable, finding the parent stack frame will be impossible unless information about it was stored in some thread-static location prior to calling the outside function.

Comment: @supercat You assume that the stack must be standardized and walked by the std exception handling code. It may be done that way by convention but it doesn't have to be that way. The stack doesn't have to walked back. All we need is to let each function do its own cleanup, which by definition it knows how to do. The requirement that the poping of the stack be done by the std exception code seems completely artificial to me. Maybe I'm missing smthg but it seems gratuitous.

Comment: @curiousguy: There are many mechanisms via which exceptions can be handled.  No particular "cost" or limitation is unavoidable, but certain costs can only be avoided by accepting certain limitations, and certain limitations can only be avoided by accepting certain costs (or other limitations).

Comment: @curiousguy: Also, an example of an optimization which would be precluded by the possibility of a function throwing would be code which allocates storage via `new` or `malloc`, then calls another function, and then releases the storage via `delete` or `free`.  If the nested function cannot throw, the storage could be allocated on the stack since it's guaranteed to be freed before control leaves the outer function.  If the nested function were to throw, however, any pointers to that storage should remain valid--something that couldn't happen if it were allocated on the stack.

Comment: @supercat Do real compilers (in C or C++) optimize away malloc/free that way?

Comment: @curiousguy: They do, and even moreso new/delete, where the Standard *expressly* allows compilers to consolidate or eliminate allocations *even when using custom allocators* (provided release operations are treated likewise, of course).